# Django: Filter based on foreignkey's start date and end date

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have the following two models:

```
class ParentModel(models.model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length = 256, blank = True)    
    start_date = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True)


class ChildModel(models.model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length = 256, blank = True)    
    parent_model = models.ForeignKey(ParentModel, blank = True, null = True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    start_date = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True)
```

Now I want to filter all the childmodel's whose date range is not within the date range of the associated parentmodel's date range.

The code I tried:

```
import pandas as pd

child_models = ChildModel.objects.filter(start_date__lte=input_end_date, end_date__gte=input_start_date)
exceeding_child_models = []

for child_model in child_models:
    date_range = pd.date_range(start=child_model.start_date, end=child_model.end_date)
    if child_model.start_date not in date_range or child_model.end_date not in date_range:
        exceeding_child_models.append(child_model)
```

How can I do that using Django ORM in a single query?

Comment: Are the `start` and `end_date` inclusive? or exclusive? This is important because the question is if a range from 2021-10-4 to 2021-10-6 overlaps with a range from 2021-10-6 to 2021-10-7 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two intervals *[s<sub>1</sub>, e<sub>1</sub>]* and *[s<sub>2</sub>, e<sub>2</sub>]* do *not* overlap if *s<sub>1</sub> > e<sub>2</sub>* or *s<sub>2</sub> > e<sub>1</sub>*.

We thus can check this with:

```
from django.db.models import F, Q

ChildModel.objects.filter(
    Q(start_date__gt=F('parent_model__end_date')) |
    Q(end_date__lt=F('parent_model__start_date'))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In reply to your comment, I want it to be inclusive. Meaning even if one among the start_date or end_date of childmodel is inside and the other is outside the date range, then also I want those choldmodels to be filtered in this query.